# I would like to know how to use wildcards in a conditional expression

Tags: bash

I have a directory that may contain multiple file types.  I'm trying to use conditional expressions to perform actions only if certain file types exist in the directory.

For example, if xml files exist then move them elsewhere.  The following statement is not working and I don't know why.

```
[ -e *.xml ] && mv *.xml ../xml
```

I've also tried double brackets without success.  Any suggestions/explanations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `find`, no need to check for their existence. if present they will be moved else command will end without any error:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -type f -exec mv {} /path/to/dest/ \;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `-e` operator expects a single file, but `*.xml` could expand to more than one. There isn't really a good way to handle this solely in shell; I would use `find`:

```
find -name '*.xml' -execdir mv '{}' ../xml +
```

One shell-only solution is to abuse a `for` loop:

```
for f in *.xml; do
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && mv *.xml ../xml
    break
done
```

This doesn't iterate, but it does allow `f` to be set to either the first of one or more matches, or to the literal string `*.xml`. Either way, the `mv` command is executed only if at least one file matches the pattern, then we exit the loop. A little clean is to use the `nullglob` option to never enter the loop if the pattern doesn't match:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.xml; do
    mv *.xml ../xml
    break
done
```

You might also use an array:

```
files=( *.xml )
[[ -f "${files[0]}" ]] && mv *.xml ../xml
```

or the positional parameters

```
set -- *.xml
[[ -f $1 ]] && mv *.xml
```

Comment: I found that -e and -d will work with the * wildcard if the expansion only results in one result.  The command that I was trying works with one xml file in the directory but fails if there are more.

Comment: The reason is that the `[` or `[[` command never sees the wild-card, only the resulting expansion. When the first argument is `-e` or `-d`, the final command can only have one more argument.